# Returning the UK Post Code only part of a Google Maps geocode result

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following line of code from the Google Maps API V3 sample:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

```
var full_address = results[1].formatted_address;
```

What I want to do is get the Post Code part from this address string. How would I do that?

Is there a method I've missed out on or is there some kind of String expression which would cut that part out for me?

Thanks,

A

Answer (score 0):

The postcode is returned as [a component of the address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingAddressTypes). Here is an example of how you might look for it in the result:

```
new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({
        'address': '20 Broadwick Street, London',
        'latLng': google.maps.LatLng(51.5136905, -0.1354)
    },
    function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            address = results[0].address_components;
            for (p = address.length-1; p >= 0; p--) {
                if (address[p].types.indexOf("postal_code") != -1) {
                    console.log(address[p].long_name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Hope that helps.