# How to reverse geocode from city to zipcode using Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to figure out an easy/free way to reverse geocode from city name to zipcode using the google maps v3 api.

Example using Seattle

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=seattle&sensor=false
```

It doesn't return the zipcode (I am aware there can be more than one per city but I would be happy with just the default or whatever I can get)

How can I take this data and then get a zipcode?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: See this similar question [How to get Indian postal pincode using google map's lat & long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700035/how-to-get-indian-postal-pincode-using-google-maps-lat-long/16704959#16704959) and [this example from it](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since in big cities there is more than one zip code, you must specify an valid address to get it. For example for http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Green+Wood+9206+1st+Ave+NW+Seattle&sensor=false

in the results JSON you get this pair:

```
        {
           "long_name" : "98117",
           "short_name" : "98117",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
```

which I suppose is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for helping!... However... I only have the City... Hence the reason I confused :-/

Comment: if you only have the city usually you can do this: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=seattle+seattle&sensor=false but of course this could change, it's better if you specify the address as mush as you can, adding the state, country etc, otherwise GoogleMaps will give you a "list of the possibilities".

Comment: hmmm... I tried this and it does work for some cities but not others: Ex. santa barbara doesn't work

Comment: As I said you need more informations to get the correct ZIP code. Some cities are split up in a number of zip codes, so you need to provide a more accurate location.

Comment: There must be a reliable way... :-/