# How to get postal code by address

Tags: php, google-maps, google-places-api

I would like to get the postal code by enter address, I have tried google auto complete place search, But it gives wrong postal code for some places.

Give any idea to get the correct postal code by the given address?

Thank you,

Comment: please share what you have tried so far

Comment: related question: [How to get Indian postal pincode using google map's lat & long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700035/how-to-get-indian-postal-pincode-using-google-maps-lat-long)

Comment: Thank you, I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code this may be helps to you:

```
// Decode json
$decoded_json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false'));

foreach($decoded_json->results as $results)
{

    foreach($results->address_components as $address_components)
    {
        // Check types is set then get first element (may want to loop through this to be safe,
        // rather than getting the first element all the time)
        print_r($address_components);
        if(isset($address_components->types) && $address_components->types[0] == 'postal_code')
        {
                    // Do what you want with data here
            echo $address_components->long_name;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=zaminkollankondan+Tamilnadu+india&sensor=false

Comment: @vinoth Didn't getting you from just a link.

Comment: I have searched above mentioned address, But the original postal code is '626142'. But it is given 626141.. please refer the following link and above link http://www.indiapost.gov.in/pincodesearch.aspx

Comment: @vinoth Please refer [http://prntscr.com/9p2d9g](http://prntscr.com/9p2d9g), for me both have same poztal_code

Comment: Thank you for your response.. Actually this is wrong postal code, In Government site postal code is correct.. Google is gives wrong postal code in some areas, how resolve this like of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will help you.

```
      <?php 

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect");

    mysqli_select_db($db, "search_db") or die("No database");

    $textbox = "";
    $out = "";
    $title = "";
    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {

    $searchq = $_GET['search'];



    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `pincodes_db` WHERE `pincode` LIKE '%$searchq%' OR `divisionname` LIKE '%$searchq%' OR `statename` LIKE '%$searchq%' OR `regionname` LIKE '%$searchq%' OR `officename` LIKE '%$searchq%' OR `circlename` LIKE '%$searchq%'" ) or die("Could not search");

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 0){

        $output = 'There was no records found';

        }else{


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

            $pincode = $row['pincode'];
            $officename = $row['officename'];
            $Deliverystatus = $row['Deliverystatus'];
                    $divisionname = $row['divisionname'];
                            $Taluk = $row['Taluk'];
                                            $RelatedHeadoffice = $row['RelatedHeadoffice'];
                                                    $RelatedSuboffice = $row['RelatedSuboffice'];
                                                                    $circlename = $row['circlename'];
                                                                    $regionname = $row['regionname'];
                                                                    $contactno = $row['Telephone'];



          $out .= '<div  style="border-bottom:1px dotted green;">

          <h2 style="font-size:18px;"><a href="search-indian-postal-code-in-map.php?postalcodeof='.$pincode.'"/><b><font color="green">Postal code of :</font></b><b><font color="green">'.$pincode.'</font></b> <b><font color="green">'.$officename.'</font></b> <b><font 

color="green">'.$regionname.'</font>,</b> <b><font color="green">'.$circlename.'</font>,</b> <b><font color="green">'.$contactno.'</font></b></a></h2>


      <table><tr><th>Description</th><th>Result</th></tr><tr>

      <td>Pincode</td>
      <td>' .$pincode.'</td></tr>

      <td>Office Name</td>
      <td>' .$officename. '</td></tr>

      <td>Delivery system</td>
      <td>' . $Deliverystatus. '</td></tr>

      <td>Division Name</td>
      <td>' . $divisionname. '</td></tr>

      <td>Taluk</td>
      <td>' . $Taluk. '</td></tr>

      <td>Related Head Office</td>
      <td>' . $RelatedHeadoffice. '</td></tr>

      <td>Related Sub Office</td>
      <td>' . $RelatedSuboffice. '</td></tr>

      <td>Circle Name</td>
      <td>' . $circlename. '</td></tr>

      <td>Region</td>
      <td>' . $regionname. '</td></tr>

      <table/></div>';


            }


        }
}

?>
```

i have used same code for my website Please refer

http://www.myworkbook.in/indian-postal-code-search/indian-states.php

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.